# How to implement a background process using parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am developing an iphone app for referrals. It uses Parse to maintain users, contacts, and referrals. It also uses Core Data to synchronize with Parse and maintain offline activities. It has a refresh method that synchronizes Parse with Core Data. I am trying to find a way that as soon as the user leaves the app, synchronization with Parse is done in the background. I have been testing using a simple parse query in applicationDidEnterBackground, but is not working. Here is the code I used:

```
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{

   self.backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
       [application endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
       self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
   }];

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       NSString *message = @"begin background task";
       NSDictionary *dict =  @{@"status": message};
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:kBeginBackgroundTaskWithNameKey];

       PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Referral"];

       [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
           if (!error) {
               NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"array has %lu objects", (unsigned long)objects.count];
               NSDictionary *dict =  @{@"status": message};
               [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:kBeginBackgroundTaskWithNameKey];

               [application endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
               self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
           }

       }];    
   });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to solve my problem. I used Ray Wenderlich tutorial "Background Modes in iOS" for guidance http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios. Here the main changes in AppDelegate:

-(void)parseSync{

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // Parse code ....

});


self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    NSLog(@"Background handler called. Not running background tasks anymore.");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];
```

}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{

  [self parseSync];

}